# Why does X-mirror and Topology mirror hide mesh when all vertices are selected and translated? How can I view my mesh again?

Tags: mesh, mirror, topology

I'm not sure if this is a bug as I can replicate the problem...which is odd because I'm using 2.77 which isn't a beta version as far as I know. I've tried researching but haven't come up with much. It'd be faster to simply remake the mesh, but I'm curious since I can replicate the problem but can't find a similar question.

***Steps:***

1- Enabled X-mirror and Topology mirror in Editmode

2- Selected all vertices and pressed "G"

3- Mesh disappears

***Outcome:***

- The object origin is still visible in 3D view.
- The object is still existent in Outliner
- The object is not hidden in Outliner.
- "Alt H" does nothing in 3D view (object not hidden by "H")
- The view is not in local view.
- “View selected” responds and zooms to object origin dot.

Thoughts?

[image: Image 1]

[image: IMage 2]

Comment: Please add Blender screen capture images to help clarify your question.

Comment: What is the vertex count in the Info window in object mode? In edit mode before the attempted grab what is the vertex count?  After G, when you press A to [select all] what is the vertex count? 0 zero or non zero 0?  Have you deleted all vertices somehow?

Comment: cegaton I'm on mac. atomicbezierslinger That was my first thought but vertices all still there. Mentalist I used to watch that show too. It's not a modifier, just a option in toolbox>options.

Comment: In the bottom right hand corner, second image: Blender is responding to grab -- it's in translate mode.

Comment: HD graphics 5000. I double checked to make sure blender is using it, and it is. I also tried telling blender to just use CPU and problem still exists.

Comment: Can you [post the .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: A couple more things: In object mode hit Ctrl A to apply scale. Have you checked your clip distance? You are working at a huge scale.

Comment: My file is 10mb too big for that exchange. I've adjusted my clipping distance to default, I loaded the factory setting file and appended the object,  and also tried scaling down my object so it's somewhat proportional to a default grid but the mesh still disappears. I'll try making my file smaller.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1158" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1158/)

Comment: I deleted most vertices to make the file fit and it's acting even stranger then before. I've discovered that hitting G again will bring the mesh back, but it's not working on the mesh I hid accidentally -- you can see it in the outliner

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the additional odd behaviours I noticed afterwards. The mesh only started disappearing in grab (even without x-mirror applied) only after the first time I used X-mirror on it. Before hand I was working on it and using the grab tool constantly. I made the mesh from scratch using a plane. I also didn't touch the script file, and started everything in the 2.77 version. Frankly, out of all my projects, this should be the last mesh to act up which is making me increasingly curious.

Comment: I looked at your .blend and the behavior is the same for me. I noticed that the translation values while grabbing read "Dx: nan Dy: nan Dz: nan" meaning "not a number". So Blender can't compute it. Why? Maybe the mesh data is corrupt. I also noticed that if I do Cursor to Selected the 3D Cursor's coordinates all go to "nan" and it disappears from view. Strange behavior, indeed. I would [file a bug report.](https://developer.blender.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh contains a lot of bad data, you should find that this bad data is causing the issues you are having.

With your object in edit mode, change to vertex select mode and de-select all vertices. With the mouse over part of the mesh press <kbd>L</kbd> - this will select all vertices linked to what is under the cursor. I see 748 vertices selected by this method.

[image: info bar]

I find that doing a select inverse and deleting the unconnected vertices still leaves some bad data. The following script deletes vertices that have one or more location values identified as NaN ([Not a Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)) which would be the reason you are having issues. After running this script I see 555 remaining vertices and find I can work with the remaining mesh and don't see any visual change.

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
bad_verts = 0

for v in bm.verts:
    if isnan(v.co[0]) or isnan(v.co[1]) or isnan(v.co[2]):
        bad_verts += 1
        bm.verts.remove(v)

print('Removed {} bad vertices'.format(bad_verts))

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I sort of had that idea, but thanks for describing it in the right language. After L select>inverse>delete and running the script 46, 209 out of the original 144,440 remain. However that doesn't solve my problem for the mesh that isn't displaying (other object in the file). I ran the script and "Removed 0 bad vertices". Here is the original: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1162" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1162/)